# Laravel cannot eager load specific field of a MorphOne

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have an Assignment model that contains a MorphOne to a MessageThread model.

```
class Assignment extends Model
{

    /**
     * @return MorphOne<\App\MessageThread>
     */
    public function messageThread(): MorphOne
    {
        return $this->morphOne("App\MessageThread", "messageable");
    }
}



class MessageThread extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var string[]
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        "messageable_id",
        "messageable_type",
        "status",
        "account_id",
        "public",
        "title",
        "direct",
    ];

    public function users(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            "App\User",
            "message_thread_user",
        )->withPivot("read");
    }

    public function messages(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany("App\Message");
    }

    public function messageable(): MorphTo
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

The following code loads the MessageThread relationship for each Assignment

```
$assignments = \App\Assignment::where("account_id", $account_id)
            ->with("messageThread")
            ->withCount(["logs", "messages"])
            ->paginate(30);


List of objects: [

    {
      "id": 378065,
        ...,
      "message_thread": {
        "id": 159809,
        ...,
        "messageable_type": "App\\Assignment",
        "created_at": "2022-08-26T20:36:38.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-08-26T20:36:38.000000Z",
      }
    }
]
```

However, I just want to load the id of the Message Thread. I don't need to load the whole model. When I search for how to do this, it looks like I need to replace the with query:

```
$assignments = \App\Assignment::where("account_id", $account_id)
            ->with("messageThread:id")
            ->withCount(["logs", "messages"])
            ->paginate(30);
```

I've also tried doing a query selector, which to my understanding is the more verbose method for doing `messageThread:id`.

```
$assignments = \App\Assignment::where("account_id", $account_id)
            ->with(["messageThread" => function ($query) {
                $query->select("id");
            }])->withCount(["logs", "messages"])
            ->paginate(30);
```

The problem is that I end up with a null value for message_thread in the JSON response:

```
[
    {
      "id": 378065,
        ...,
      "message_thread": null
    },
]
```

I know the problem isn't that the MessageThread doesn't exist because it loads completely fine if I don't specify a column.

I've tried searching for this kind of error, but have come up blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`messageable_id` needs to be included in the select in order to match Assignment and MessageThread models

```
 $assignments = \App\Assignment::where("account_id", $account_id)
    ->with(["messageThread" => function ($query) {
        $query->select("message_thread.id, message_thread.messageable_id");
    }])
    ->withCount(["logs", "messages"])
    ->paginate(30);
```

laracasts credit: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/select-columns-on-relationship-tables?page=1&replyId=755706

Comment: I changed the case and it still returns null

Comment: Can you please share your both relationships with us?

Comment: I can't share the entire models, but I added the relevant parts

Comment: can you please check my editted answer?

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked! Can you clarify how you found the solution? I can't find anything in the Eloquent documentation relating to this.

Comment: added the laracast reference to the answer